# When is $\left\{\frac{1}{2}x_1+\frac{1}{2}x_2\right\}=\left\{\frac{1}{3}x_3+\frac{1}{3}x_4+\frac{1}{3}x_5\right\}$

Tags: convex-analysis

Let $X$ be a non convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Is it possible that the sets
$$S_2=\left\{\dfrac{1}{2}x_1+\dfrac{1}{2}x_2,x_i\in X\right\}$$ and $$S_3=\left\{\dfrac{1}{3}x_3+\dfrac{1}{3}x_4+\dfrac{1}{3}x_5,x_i\in X\right\}$$ are equal? If yes is there any characterization of these sets $X$?

Comment: If $X$ has more than one point, say that $x\neq y\in X$, we have that $\frac12x+\frac12x=\frac13y+\frac13y+\frac13y$, a contradiction.

Comment: I will edit my question, since I had something else in my head.

Answer (score 1):

If two different points $x,y\in X$, then
$$\frac12x+\frac12x=\frac13y+\frac13y+\frac13y$$
that is
$$x=y$$
a contradiction.

Then $X$ is empty or has only one point, so it is hardly non convex.